# when i click on marker a new marker is creating on map in android

Tags: android

Am getting data from server and adding multiple markers on map.
when i long click on a marker a new marker is creating with same info window on map and its repeating.
 I dnt no where the problem can anyone help me

```
  if(Points.size()>0)

{
    for (int j = 0; j < staus.size(); j++) {
        if (staus.get(j).equals("Run")) {
            if (Vtype.get(j).equalsIgnoreCase("M/C")) {
                marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(Points.get(j)).title(r_vn)
                        .snippet("").draggable(true)
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.mc_run)));
            }

            if (Vtype.get(j).equalsIgnoreCase("Car")) {
                marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(Points.get(j)).title(r_vn)
                        .snippet("").draggable(true)
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.car_run)));
            }


        }
    }


    Log.i("livestatus la", String.valueOf(Points));

    LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
    for (LatLng latLng : Points) {
        builder.include(latLng);
        if (Current_latlong != null) {
            //builder.include(Current_latlong);
        }
    }
    int width = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
    int height = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
    int padding = (int) (width * 0.10);
    final LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
    CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, width, height, padding);
    mMap.animateCamera(cu);

}
```

Comment: show some more code of your marker click or markerdraglistener

Comment: just remove the marker click listener i am pretty sure you are creating a new marker up there.

Comment: sry i found my mistake,instead  of draggable(false) i used true